# React: Execute a Function as many times as it is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to give an image a addEventListener `click` listener, but it happens only once by itself when the localhost refreshes and nothing happens after I try to click the image.

I added `window.onload`  so that the JS executes after the DOM has been loaded, I have tried this in a separate JS file also but same thing happens.

The react code and javascript:

```
// React and all other imports

export default function Women() {
    
    //All the image variables in an array
    var images = [b1, b10, b11, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b2 , b3, b12];

    window.onload = function() {
      var firstWomen = document.querySelector(".women-product-image").firstChild;

      firstWomen.addEventListener("click", 
       console.log("click successful")
     )
   }

    return (
        <div>
           {images.map(image =>
            <div className="women-product-card" >
                <div className="women-product-image">
                    <img src={image} alt="product-image" width="200px" />
                </div>
                 <div  className="women-product-detail">
                    <h5>Lorem Ipsum</h5>
                    <p className="women-product-price" >&#x20B9;2,999</p>
                    
                    <button>Add to Cart</button>
                    <img src={star} width="20px" className="women-star-fav" />
                </div>
                
            </div>
            )}
      </div>
    )
}
```

When I save this and the localhost refreshes it gives `click successful` by itself in the Developer Tools console and when I try to click the first image nothing happens.

I want my first image to have a permanent eventListener so that the user clicks it how many times it gives the result everytime.

Thankyou in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to add an `onClick` prop to the `div` with the `women-product-image` class. This way the onClick callback would always be available. In order to add the prop to the first one you can use the index returning from the `map`.
So something like:

```
{images.map((image, index) =>
<div className="women-product-card" onClick={index === 0 ? () => console.log('clicked!') :  null}>
.... // the rest of your code
</div>
```

This can be achieved a bit more elegantly but the idea would probably be the same or similiar

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to add the onClick prop only on the first child, but this will do it on all the <div>s, is there any way to just add it on the first child only?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed that, will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

you can add click to image directly.

```
// React and all other imports

export default function Women() {
    
    //All the image variables in an array
    const images = [b1, b10, b11, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b2 , b3, b12];
    const onImageClick = () => {
      alert('Image clicked')
    }

    return (
        <div>
           {images.map((image, index) =>
            <div className="women-product-card" >
                <div className="women-product-image">
                    <img src={image} alt="product-image" width="200px" onClick={index === 0 ? onImageClick : null} />
                </div>
                 <div  className="women-product-detail">
                    <h5>Lorem Ipsum</h5>
                    <p className="women-product-price" >&#x20B9;2,999</p>
                    
                    <button>Add to Cart</button>
                    <img src={star} width="20px" className="women-star-fav" />
                </div>
                
            </div>
            )}
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to add it on the first child only, but it will do it to all the Images, any way to just add it on the first Image only?